# Spring Boot - program arguments in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

How can I include program arguments in `application.properties`?

For example: `java Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--redis.host=localhost -jar build/libs/app.jar`

application.properties:

```
spring.redis.url=redis://${redis.host}:6379
```

Is it possible to replace ${redis.host} with the value coming from the program arguments? (localhost in the exampe)

Comment: You may need to use `PropertySourcePlaceholderCOnfigurer`. https://dzone.com/articles/spring-core-diving-into-the-propertyplaceholdercon. And you will need to pass properties like `-Dredis.host=localhost`

Comment: @Ivan using SpringBoot, passing the property as -Dredis.host=localhost on its own solves the problem. I will accept this info as the correct answer, if you write it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass your properties like `-Dredis.host=localhost`.

```
java -Dredis.host=localhost -jar <your jar>
```

Comment: `java -jar <your jar> --spring.redis.host=localhost` [set-spring-boot-properties-via-command-line-argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000750/set-spring-boot-properties-via-command-line-argument#60000881)