# Set spring boot properties via command line argument

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I have 2 properties files:

- application.yml
- bootstrap.yml

I have embedded jar file for my application, and launch it with: `java -jar 'jar file path'`
I need to override properties files with files in external location.

Tried: `-Dspring.config.location=your/config/dir/` argument, however it does't work.

**Could you advice me proper approach how to override properties with several properties files, please?**

My bootstrap.yml looks like:

```
spring:
  application.name: app_name
  profiles:
    active: local
    include:
  cloud.consul.enabled: false
  main:
    web-application-type: none

---
spring:
  profiles: withconsul
  cloud:
    config.allow-override: true
    consul:
      enabled: true
      host: https://consul.evoil.ru
      port: 443
      config:
        enabled: true
        format: YAML
        fail-fast: true
```

**Should I rename properties file regarding existing profiles?**

Answer (score 1):

You also need to use **spring.config.name** besides the **spring.config.location**.

```
java -jar 'jar file path' --spring.config.name=external-prop-file-name --spring.config.location=your/config/dir/
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files.

**Update:**

If you want to apply the properties of both external files(but where the properties found in **bootstrap.yml** take precedence of the one found in **application.yml**) then you need to rename the **bootstrap.yml** file to **application-bootstrap.yml** and start the application using the **bootstrap** profile:

```
java -jar 'jar file path' --spring.profiles.active=bootstrap --spring.config.location=your/config/dir/
```

In this example I omitted the **--spring.config.name** argument because its default  value is **application**(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#core-properties).

**Update 2:**

If the **withconsul** profile is already activated in the application.yml file and you don't want to add a new profile then you can rename bootstrap.yml file to **application-withconsul.yml**.

Comment: Thank you, and in case of 2 files, how should I wright parameters in --spring.config.name=external-prop-file-name ?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example for what you are asking.

Comment: I have updated question, please check if I understand you correctly